# WPF MVVM: Async method does not always update the UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I bound a button to a command in the view model that triggers a long-running operation. The operation is run in a separate task. Before and after the task, a property is set to reflect it running in the UI.

My problem now is: Sometimes, when I click the button, the change of the property BEFORE the long operation runs is registered (i.e., the UI changes accordingly), but when the task finishes, it is not immediately. I have to click somewhere in the UI to make the change to be reflected.

Here is how I did it (using MVVM Light):

```
_longRunningOpCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await DoLongRunningThingAsync(), CanDoLongRunningThing);

// ...

public ICommand LongRunningOpCommand { get { return _longRunningOpCommand; } }

// ...

private async Task DoLongRunningThingAsync() {
    try {
        IsDoingStuff = true; // triggers a PropertyChangeEvent, is bound to UI
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
            await _something.DoLenghtyOperation();
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    } finally {
        IsDoingStuff = false;
    }
}
```

Now, the UI elements update as soon as `IsDoingStuff` is becoming `false` as they should, but they are not updated when `IsDoingStuff` is becoming `true`. I have to click into the UI to have them updated.

I think I'm doing something wrong, but can't track down what.

Comment: If `_something.DoLenghtyOperation` is awaitable, why run it in a new Task?

Comment: Because otherwise, the UI is not updated as long as `_something.DoLenghtyOperation` is running.

Comment: Yeah, you're messing with tasks. Task.Factory.StartNew is not recommended for your scenario. So as to the IsDoingStuff property - change it with Application.Current.Dispatcher. As you're in async method use InvokeAsync().